# Limitations of the Perl Tie::File module

Tags: perl

I tried using the [`Tie:File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie:File) module to write a text file which should be containing 1 billion lines, but it throws an error after writing 16 million

```
"Out of memory!"

"Callback called exit at C:/perl/lib/Tie/File.pm line 979 during global destruction."
```

this is the code I tried with.

```
    use Tie::File;

    tie @array, 'Tie::File', "Out.txt";

    $start = time();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 15000000; $i++) {
       $array[$i].= "$i,";
    }

    $end = time();

    print("time taken: ", $end - $start, "seconds");
    untie @array;
```

I don't know why it throws an error. Any solutions to overcome this? It also took about 55 minutes to write 16 million records and it throws error! Is this usual time it takes to write?

Comment: The problem is that you're accumulating all of the data in memory prior to writing it out to the file. What you should do is generate the data piecewise and write out the pieces, only keeping one piece in memory at a time.  If possible, only a single row at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Tie:File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie:File) module is known to be quite slow, and it is best used where the advantage of having random access to the lines of the file outweighs the poor performance.

But this isn't a problem with the module, it is a limitation of Perl. Or, more accurately, a limitation of your computer system. If you take the module out of the situation and just try to create an ordinary array with 1,000,000,000 elements then Perl will die with an `Out of memory!` error. The limit for my 32-bit build of Perl 5 version 20 is around 30 million. For 64-bit builds it will be substantially more.

`Tie:File` *doesn't* keep the whole file in memory but pages it in and out to save space, so it *can* handle very large files. Just not *that* large!

In this case you don't have any need of the advantages of `Tie:File`, and you should just write the data sequentially to the file. Something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '>', 'Out.txt';

my $time = time;

for my $i (0 .. 15_000_000) {
   print $fh "$i,\n";
}

$time = time - $time;

printf "Time taken: %d seconds\n", $time;
```

This program ran in seven seconds on my system.

Please also note `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of the program. This is *essential* for any Perl program, and will quickly reveal many simple problems that you would otherwise overlook. With `use strict` in place, each variable must be declared with `my` as close as possible to the first point of use.

Comment: @Nemo: I'm not certain, but I think that's a consequence of increasing the size of the array from zero by one element at a time. That may well cause a lot of memory reallocation and Perl doesn't release free memory back to the system. If I'm right then you should get a lot of improvement if you preallocate the array, even though it isn't a real array. Try setting the size of the array right after the `tie` with `$#array = 8_999_999` (for 9 million elements) and then write values into it.

Comment: will this be useful for writing more than one column ? i have to write another column after writing a column !

Comment: @lazy: This method will work fine with whatever data you want to write to a file. You shouldn't use `Tie::File` if you're just writing a new file or appending to the lines of en existing one - it will be many times slower than just opening the file and writing to it. I suggest you open a new question and show your complete problem so that we can help.