# Suggestion for writing in a file using module

Tags: perl

I need to write a file with more than one column, and the row count in the billions. I don't know whether to follow the row approach or the column approach. Each column will contain different values.

I tried earlier using the [`Tie:File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie:File) module, but it was very slow and ran out of memory. Please suggest some ideas.

my output file data would be like this :

```
001|jhon|12, avenue street|234221|newyork
002|sam|broad street|535251|berlin
003|raju|15/a, street|4234614|jersy
```

number of columns and row size may vary !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425132/limitations-of-the-perl-tiefile-module/

Comment: If you're having a choice always access files line by line (row by row). Thinking otherwise implies total inexperience, not only in programming in general, but in understanding of basic things like files.

Comment: @lazy: So that we can help you better, please describe what experience you have with Perl, and with programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help a little to see what your data looked like, but remember that there are no "columns" in a text file except as defined by the software that reads it. You probably want a CSV (comma-separated values) file, in which case you can just use the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) operator if you can guarantee that the data contains no commas or double-quotes. Or you may need the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module which will allow you any sort of complexity in your data.

Here's a couple of examples:

**Using `join`**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my @data = (
  [qw/ 1 2 3 /],
  [qw/ A B C /],
  [qw/ a b c/],
);

open my $fh, '>', 'mycsv1.csv';

for my $row (@data) {
  print $fh join(',', @$row), "\n";
}

close $fh;
```

**output**

```
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
```

**Using `Text::CSV`**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my @data = (
  [ 'data1', 'data2', 'data3' ],
  [ '"data1"', 'data "with quotes" 2', 'data "3"' ],
  [ 'data,1', 'data, with commas, 2', 'data, number 3' ],
  [ '"data","1"', 'data, with "quotes" and "commas", 2', 'data, "number 3"' ],
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ eol => $/ });
open my $fh, '>', 'mycsv2.csv';

for my $row (@data) {
  $csv->print($fh, $row);
}

close $fh;
```

**output**

```
data1,data2,data3
"""data1""","data ""with quotes"" 2","data ""3"""
"data,1","data, with commas, 2","data, number 3"
"""data"",""1""","data, with ""quotes"" and ""commas"", 2","data, ""number 3"""
```

Comment: @Nemo: Both the `join` and `Text::CSV` solution have this potential problem. We haven't been told anything about the data, so I have used arrays only as a data source for the example. The real code will have to generate the data line by line at run time.

Comment: The problem is in not in using `join` or `Text::CSV`, but in storing all the data in an array prior to writing it out.